# MATLAB Bar Graph Plotting Over Axes

Tags: matlab, panel, bar-chart

I have a troubling problem that I've been trying to figure out for quite a while now and I just have no clue why it's happening. I have a self-coded GUI and I have a panel on the main GUI figure. On this panel I have an axes and whenever I plot a bar graph on that axes and try to edit its view with either yLim() or axis(), the axes will be resized to the dimensions I want, but the bar graph will not chop off at the edge of the axes and it will continue to run off the page. After playing around with it for a while in debug mode, I have found out that if I change the axes' parent from the panel it's on to the main figure, the bar graph will properly display only what is inside the axes borders like I want it to. I don't want to use changing the axes' parent as a permanent solution since I have several different panels I want to go between and having an axes on the main figure instead of the panel wouldn't work but I'd like to know if anybody knows why this is happening and how I can fix it.

For example, this code produces the problem I'm experiencing:

```
mainFig = figure('Units','characters',...
    'Position',[40 5 200 50],...
    'Color',[100/255 145/255 209/255]);
axesPanel = uipanel('bordertype','etchedin',...
    'Parent',mainFig,...
    'Title','Axes Panel');
mainAxes = axes('parent',axesPanel,...
    'Units','characters');
bar(mainAxes,1:10,1:10)
ylim(mainAxes,[6 10])
```

And if the axes' parent is changed to be the figure, the problem doesn't exist. This line of code does that:

```
set(mainAxes,'parent',mainFig)
```

Thanks for any help or information as to why this is happening!

Comment: You may be better off submitting a tech support request to Mathworks. This seems like an issue in the implementation of `bar`, since there is no issue when you substitute `bar` for a basic `plot`. Nothing jumps out when comparing the properties before & after the ylim and parent adjustments are made.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to think it was a problem on MATLAB's end that I didn't have control of so I'll submit a tech support request, but I was just really hoping there would be a way to get it to work on a panel without having to find a different way to represent my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anybody else was having this same problem, I contacted MATLAB Technical Support and I was told that this was a bug on MATLAB's end that is being fixed in the next release(R2014b). They said that if you are having the problem I described in my original question, that in order to make the bar graph appear within the axes' boundaries at the moment, that you can edit the figure's 'Renderer' property and set it to either 'opengl' or 'zbuffer'. I have tested this and both options work so hopefully that helps :)

And just for extra clarification if it is needed, all I needed to change from my original code was:

```
mainFig = figure('Units','characters',...
    'Position',[40 5 200 50],...
    'Color',[100/255 145/255 209/255]);
```

To this:

```
mainFig = figure('Units','characters',...
    'Renderer','opengl',...
    'Position',[40 5 200 50],...
    'Color',[100/255 145/255 209/255]);
```

And now the bar graph behaves as it should.